# How does .Net runtime "understand" that structure still has a reference

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

The question is how .Net runtime understands that fields of a structure, that was placed onto memory using `Marshal.StructureToPtr`, must not be freed by GC.

Below the scenario.

I have the following structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SomeStruct
{
    public string s;
    public Stream stream;

    public SomeStruct(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
        this.stream = new MemoryStream(0x100);
    }
}
```

There is a method that instantiates the structure and drops it to memory:

```
static IntPtr GetStructRawData()
{
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(new SomeStruct("hi"), ptr, false);
    return ptr;
}
```

Then I can make new structure from the raw memory:

```
IntPtr ptr = GetStructRawData();

GC.Collect();

SomeStruct struct2 = (SomeStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(SomeStruct));
```

Aftet that `struct2` really contains correct string ("hi"), and correct stream. So it seems that there are references to that string and to that stream of `struct1`. But what holds the references? How does the runtime understands that the string and the stream must not be collected?

Comment: btw: spans and `ref`-returns make it much easier to work with this kind of data without needing `Marshal` or `unsafe` everywhere. I'd strongly recommend using them! also, both spans and `ref` values *work through the GC*

Comment: Interestingly, your `MemoryStreams` are being kept alive by RefCount handles. I've no idea why they're being introduced here though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what holds the references? How does the runtime understands that the string and the stream must not be collected?

The `string` here is a bit of a special case; it is actually an interned string (loaded via `ldstr`), so it is already rooted by the intern table.

The `MemoryStream` however... frankly, **it isn't rooted**. Your code is inherently broken and dangerous, and it could fail horribly at any time. The objects could be collected or moved (compaction) at any time, and that would leave broken references in the unmanaged memory, because the GC **isn't looking at the unmanaged memory**.

I believe your code is only "working" currently because the GC hasn't been aggressive with you. Also keep in mind: GC doesn't *erase* objects; if the GC *just* decided to consider the `MemoryStream` as collected, you might still be able to talk to it again *without it complaining*, if the memory still looks OK for a while. But this is just working for the wrong reasons.

Having *references* in unmanaged memory is a terrible terrible idea and **will hurt you**.

If you're going to use unmanaged memory, the `where T : unmanaged` constraint could be a life-saver for you. It prevents you getting into this scenario, but **as a necessity** restricts what you can do. Meaning: you can't *have* these fields.

Comment: Aha! That's what I thought because it's quite obviously that nobody owns that stream. The sample is artificial, and, of course, such code will never be used in real world.

Answer (score 3):

Per Marc's comment I've updated my answer.

I modified your program a bit and looked at it in WinDbg to understand it better. In your example the literal string is rooted by the string interning table, which is a static so it will keep all literal strings alive for the lifetime of the process.

If I change your string to be a dynamically created, it is no longer rooted by this table. Instead, as soon as you leave `GetStructRawData` the `!gcroot` command reports that the string is no longer rooted. I.e. from the GC's point of view it is no more,  it has ceased to be, it is bereft of life, it rests in peace, it is an ex-string.

I agree with Marc that the reason your program still works is simply by chance. You are able to restore the reference and the object just happens to be in the same location. Don't count on this.

Comment: I'm not sure this is answering the right question; I think OP is asking about the string and stream here

Comment: @MarcGravell - you're right and I was typing :) but not only did you have time to comment but also to provide a more detailed answer. +1

Comment: I was seeing something a bit different: there are RefCount handles to the `MemoryStreams`, which are acting as roots: https://imgur.com/a/V9wI3QH. The `MemoryStreams` were also being retained, even after many MBs of allocations and many forced gen2 compacting GCs

Comment: @canton7 thanks for the input. I didn't think about this, but that's a good point. Furthermore, GC is different between debug and release builds. The observations above are based on release build.

Comment: I saw the same in both Debug and Release (and Core and Framework), interestingly. RefCount handles are a COM thing AFAIK: I wonder why they're being introduced (presumably by `StructureToPtr`? here)

Comment: @canton7 did you see the string rooted?

Comment: I'd expect that to be interned, and loads of strings are allocated by the runtime so it's hard to find the one instance that contains "hi" (at least from the VS profile)